# Change phone number and display name of contact with contacts_service in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to update my single contact data using flutter contact_service dart package. I am new in flutter programming that's why don't understand that how i can do that.
that' my code.

```
enter code here
 await ContactsService.updateContact(
            Contact(displayName: "yello", phones: abcd))
        .catchError((onError) {
      print(onError.toString());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
/*this line fetches the contact whose familyName(last name) is "Jackson", incase 
if there's multiple contact with the same familyName then it'll select first one */
Contact contactToUpdate = _contacts
        .toList()
        .firstWhere((contact) => contact.familyName.startsWith("Jackson"));
//this line updates the givenName(first name) of fetched contact to "Michael"
    contactToUpdate.givenName = 'Michael';
    await ContactsService.updateContact(contactToUpdate);
```

Comment: can you tell ma that how i can update display name and contact number at same time

Comment: can you tell me there is any way to update contact number using contact_service flutter package.

Comment: But how to update only the phone number ??

Answer (score 0):

```
      Iterable<Contact> UpdatedList = await ContactsService.getContacts(
      query: 'Updated Phone',
      withThumbnails: false,
      photoHighResolution: false);
  if (Updated.length != 0) {
    print('found');
    Contact UpdatedContact = Updated.first;
    if (UpdatedContact.phones.first.value != '07938422874') {
      print('changing contact');
      UpdatedContact.phones = [Item(label: 'mobile', value: '07938422874')];
      UpdatedContact.displayName = 'Antony Leons'
     await ContactsService.updateContact(UpdatedContact);
    }
  }
```